# Threejs - Maintain aspect ratio while adding texture map to threejs object

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d-model

We want to create a 3d shoe designing tool, where you can design patterns and upload them to the shoe.

I am trying to place an image on a Threejs material. I am able to update the map, but the texture is blurry. I am new to Threejs, so I do not have concepts clear. I don't understand if aspect ratio is the issue or something else.

This how I am loading texture:

```
var texture_loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

var texture = texture_loader.load( 'https://ik.imagekit.io/toesmith/pexels-photo-414612_D4wydSedY.jpg', function ( texture ) {

    texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.offset.set( 0, 0 );
    texture.repeat.set( 1, 1 );
    vamp.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      map: texture,
      color: new THREE.Color('#f2f2f2'),
      shininess: 20,
    });
});
```

This is what I am getting

[image]

But the expected behavior should be

[image]

If anyone could help, that would be great. Thanks

Here is the link to the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ap20feb/pen/pmmLQE) code

Comment: Fixing this generally requires that you fix the shoe model's texture coordinates in a modeling package like [blender](https://blender.org). How a texture applies to a geometry is generally defined by its texture coordinates (often called UVs). This is not normally something you fix in code, you fix in them the [uv editor of some modeling package](https://www.google.com/search?q=uv+editor)

Comment: I am able to place other textures with repeat perfectly. Only, when repeat on x and y is 1, it gets blurred. I think UVs are already defined for this model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your UVs are occupying a very small area in texture coordinates. As they are now, it looks like your UVs are taking up this much room (see red area):

[image]

And that's why it gives the impression that your texture is blurry. What you need to do is make your UVs take up more space, like this:

[image]

There are 2 ways to achieve this.

1. **Scale UVs up**: Import your model into Blender, and change the UV mapping of the mesh to occupy more of the `[0, 1]` range.
2. **Scale texture down**: You could get creative with the [`texture.repeat`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture.repeat) property and use it to scale down your texture to match your existing UVs. Then you'd need to [offset](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture.offset) it so it's centered correctly. Something like:

```
texture.repeat = new THREE.Vector2(10, 10);
texture.offset = new THREE.Vector2(xx, yy);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any mathematical formula to calculate repeat x and y? Because I am not able to find the perfect values for x and y.

Comment: The formula depends on how the UV mapping was done and how you want the image to look. It's entirely up to you to do a visual assessment and see what looks right to you.

Comment: Just going to re-iterate, any professional 3D company would fix this by fixing the model's UVs in a modeling package. If the goal is to be able to place any texture there then you need to have to model designed with UVs for that in mind. Similarly if you want to texture that part of the shoe separately then your modeller would generally build that part of the shoe as a separate model to make it easy to adjust its texture and material separate from the rest of the model. By doing it any other way you're asking how to do it wrong. Every model will require manual math. Fix the model instead

Comment: Scaling texture down worked for now. Thanks for helping me out. But will get my model fixed @gman. Thanks everyone